# How To Check State of CapsLock Button with C# in Windows Store (WinRT) Application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to put a flyout warning if CapsLock button is On while typing something in PasswordBox.

I'm **NOT** trying to find out if the pressed key is CapsLock

I checked out the old,

[KeyboardDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .NET 3.5

[Control.IsKeyLocked()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked.aspx) Windows Forms

[Console.CapsLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.capslock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Not Available in Windows 8.1 Store Application

[Keyboard.GetKeyStates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.getkeystates.aspx) Not Available in Windows 8.1 Store Application

and WinApi Style calls.

None of them seems suitable, Anyone has a suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [CoreWindow.GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getasynckeystate) with a value of `VirtualKey.CapitalLock`.

You can get the current `CoreWindow` with [CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getforcurrentthread).

Additionally, you can subscribe to the [CoreWindow.KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown.aspx) and [CoreWindow.KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keyup.aspx) events to update your key status indicator.

Comment: Works only once when CapsLock pressed, that isn't what i needed

Comment: Suprisingly fixed after moving operation in a function other than KeyDown

Comment: I would add that GetAsyncKeyState() doesn't work try GetKeyState(). GetKeyState() worked for me by getAsyncKeyState did not. Also I did mine on the initialization of my page and on key up and that worked for me.